# how to get good logging for solr? and why sometimes it didn't accomplish the indexing process?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, jetty, solr

I have installed solr (lucidworks-enterprise-installer-1.7.jar) [jetty] on my server (Ubuntu 9.10), and created a cron job to build FULL index everyday morning

```
30 3 * * * curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/solr/collection1/dataimport_1?command=full-import
```

the question is: sometimes this process wipes the old index completely and doesn't create anything!!
any idea of why is this?? and any idea of how to create a neat log for solr (something like apache log)
Thanks for your help